# OAuth Implementation 2.0 Using .Net Core , Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I want to implement the OAuth 2.0 in my web application. In web application, I have used swagger and I implemented the following code.

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://myWebAppUrl", UriKind.Absolute),
                            TokenUrl = new Uri("https://myWebAppUrl"),
                        }
                    }
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement 
                {
                    { 
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" }
                        },
                        new[] { "readaccess", "writeaccess" }
                    }
                });
```

I added the above code and ran my project.
Then, On the click of Authorize I was able to see the "Authorize" button and When I clicked on "Authorize" button, I was redirected to my web app login page.

Now,
I want to validate the login credentials that the user will enter on the login page, So, I generated JWT token in my login API to validate the user's credentials.

I may have missed some steps here.

But, I am lost how to redirect back to the "Swagger Documentation" after the login is successful.
After the login is successful it redirects me to the dashboard (I don't want this).

Please help how can I proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Identity Server than you can create additional client for swagger and set redirect uri to swagger. You can start with [tutorial](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/ASPNET-Core-Swagger-UI-Authorization-using-IdentityServer4).

Comment: Actually, I am not using the Identity Server. This is my existing web application which is quite big and I have used Entity Framework, ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Swagger.There is already a Login API which is implementing the JWT. I have added the above code in the Swagger which is redirecting me to the Login Page of my web application. But, I don't know how to redirect back to swagger UI @Serhii.

Comment: @SimranKaur I think you should implement something similar with redirect uri as int identity server. Swager redirect to login page with redirect_uri=http://.../swagger/oauth2-redirect.html. After that implement check with allowed redirect uris on login page. After login your app will redirect to swagger page.

Comment: Or you could configure implicit flow in swagger